# React leaflet map show open street map transport layer

Tags: reactjs, openstreetmap, react-leaflet

I am using React leaflet map in the TileLayer I am showing below URL.

```
<TileLayer
    attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
  />
```

It shows the standard map. But I wanted to show the Transport map.

How do I accomplish this? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [OpenStreetMap Wiki Article](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Transport_Map) you have to get the tiles from [Thunderforest](https://www.thunderforest.com/maps/transport/).

`https://tile.thunderforest.com/transport/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apikey=<insert-your-apikey-here>`

Comment: Is this thunderforest is open source?

Comment: Please do some research for yourself.

https://www.thunderforest.com/about/

Comment: Thunderforest's rendering styles are not open as far as I know.